# Routing Error No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

I'm trying to get a user from his profile (user_path) can register his vehicles (new_user_car_path). but i got this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"cars"}
```

for that i have the next routes.rb

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
devise_for :users
resources :users do
resources :cars, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
end
```

here is part of the user_path

```
<div class="container">

  <fieldset>
    <h1><%= @user.email %></h1>
    <br>

    <h2>options</h2>
    <p>
    <strong>new car registration</strong>
    <%= link_to "Sign up now!", new_user_car_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>

    </p>
    <p>
    <strong>all cars view</strong>

    </p>
  </fieldset>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

and my CarsController

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @car = Car.new
    end

    def create
        @car = current_user.cars.build(params[:car])
        if @car.save
            redirect_to current_user, :flash => { :success => "car created!" }
        else
            redirect_to new_user_car_path, :flash => { :success => "sorry try again" }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass information to route, so that it can determine where to go.

if you want to create a new car for a user, you need to pass the user. otherwise rails will not know where to get the user from... which is kind of logical if you think about it for more then a second...

```
new_user_car_path(user)
```